# Comparison Error when Storing values in a List, Boolean Map

Tags: java, swing

I have a fully working version of MineSweeper implemented in Java.  However, I am trying to add an additional feature that updates a Map to store the indexes of the locations of the mines within a 2D array.  For example, if location [x][y] holds a mine, I am storing a linked list containing x and y, which maps to a boolean that is true to indicate that the space holds a mine.  (This feature is seemingly trivial, but I am just doing this to practice with Collections in Java.)

My relevant private instance variables include:

```
public Class World{ ...

private LinkedList<Integer>  index;

private Map<LinkedList<Integer>, Boolean> revealed;
```

"index" is the list to be stored in the map as the key for each boolean.

In my constructor I have:

```
 public World(){ ...

        tileArr = new Tile[worldWidth][worldHeight];
        revealed = new TreeMap<LinkedList<Integer>, Boolean>();
        index =  new LinkedList<Integer>();

        ... }
```

Now, in the method in which I place the mines, I have the following:

```
 private void placeBomb(){
        int x = ran.nextInt(worldWidth);     //Random stream
        int y = ran.nextInt(worldHeight);    //Random stream

            if (!tileArr[x][y].isBomb()){
                tileArr[x][y].setBomb(true);

                index.add(x);                //ADDED COMPONENT
                index.add(y);
                revealed.put(index, true);
                index.remove(x);
                index.remove(y);             //END OF ADDED COMPONENT


            } else placeBomb();

    }
```

Without the marked added component my program runs fine, and I have a fully working game.  However, this addition gives me the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedList 
cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

If anyone could help point out where this error might be, it would be very helpful! This is solely for additional practice with collections and is not required to run the game.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually about 3 issues here. One that you know about, one that you don't and a third which is just that using `LinkedList` as a key for a map is clunky.

1. The `ClassCastException` happens because [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is a sorted set and requires that every key in it implement the `Comparable` interface, or else you have to provide a custom `Comparator`. `LinkedList` doesn't implement `Comparable`, so you get an exception. The solution here could be to use a different map, like `HashMap`, or you could write a custom `Comparator.`

   A custom `Comparator` could be like this:

   ```
   revealed = new TreeMap<List<Integer>, Boolean>(
       // sort by x value first
       Comparator.comparing( list -> list.get(0) )
           // then sort by y if both x values are the same
           .thenComparing( list -> list.get(1) )
   );
   ```

   (And I felt compelled to include this, which is a more robust example that isn't dependent on specific elements at specific indexes):

   ```
   revealed = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<List<Integer>>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(List<Integer> lhs, List<Integer> rhs) {
           int sizeComp = Integer.compare(lhs.size(), rhs.size());
           if (sizeComp != 0) {
               return sizeComp;
           }
           Iterator<Integer> lhsIter = lhs.iterator();
           Iterator<Integer> rhsIter = rhs.iterator();
           while ( lhsIter.hasNext() && rhsIter.hasNext() ) {
               int intComp = lhsIter.next().compareTo( rhsIter.next() );
               if (intComp != 0) {
                   return intComp;
               }
           }
           return 0;
       }
   });
   ```
2. The issue that you don't know about is that you're only ever adding one `LinkedList` to the map:

   ```
   index.add(x);
   index.add(y);
   // putting index in to the map
   // without making a copy
   revealed.put(index, true);
   // modifying index immediately
   // afterwards
   index.remove(x);
   index.remove(y);
   ```

   This is unspecified behavior, because you put the key in, then modify it. The documentation for `Map` says the following about this:

   > Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects `equals` comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

   What will actually happen (for `TreeMap`) is that you are always erasing the previous mapping. (For example, the first time you call `put`, let's say `x=0` and `y=0`. Then the next time around, you set the list so that `x=1` and `y=1`. This also modifies the list inside the map, so that when `put` is called, it finds there was already a key with `x=1` and `y=1` and replaces the mapping.)

   So you could fix this by saying something like either of the following:

   ```
   // copying the List called index
   revealed.put(new LinkedList<>(index), true);
   // this makes more sense to me
   revealed.put(Arrays.asList(x, y), true);
   ```

   However, this leads me to the 3rd point.
3. There are better ways to do this, if you want practice with collections. One way would be to use a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Boolean>>`, like this:

   ```
   Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Boolean>> revealed = new HashMap<>();
   {
       revealed.computeIfAbsent(x, HashMap::new).put(y, true);
       // the preceding line is the same as saying
       // Map<Integer, Boolean> yMap = revealed.get(x);
       // if (yMap == null) {
       //     yMap = new HashMap<>();
       //     revealed.put(x, yMap);
       // }
       // yMap.put(y, true);
   }
   ```

   That is basically like a 2D array, but with a `HashMap`. (It could make sense if you had a very, very large game board.)

   And judging by your description, it sounds like you already know that you could just make a `boolean isRevealed;` variable in the `Tile` class.

Answer (score 0):

From the spec of a treemap gives me this:

> The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator provided at map creation time, depending on which constructor is used.

The Java Linkedlist can not be compared just like that. You have to give it a way to compare them or just use another type of map, that does not need sorting.